# c++ windows api SHGetImageList to get oversized icons and return 32*32 icons in some cases

Tags: c++, winapi

[image]

This application only has a 32*32 icon. After I get the icon through SHGetImageList SHIL_JUMBO and save it as a file, the icon is in the upper left corner. How to solve this problem? How to enlarge the obtained icon to 256 and then save it.

How to enlarge the obtained icon to 256, and then save it as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

That is precisely so documented? You should get `0 ... SHIL_LAST` with `SHGetImageList`. So that implies that is not designed to zoom the images beyond that `SHIL_LAST` and you say yourself that `SHIL_JUMBO` is beyond it for particular image list.

AFAIK the [GetImage of IShellItemImageFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitemimagefactory-getimage) does provide zoomed `HBITMAP` (like shown in shell) if you need zoomed images for shell item icons.

Note that it is documented to perform a GDI stretch blit.

> If the caller wants a higher quality image stretch than provided
> through that mechanism, they should pass this flag and perform the
> stretch themselves.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there any way I can tell if a file has a giant icon, so that if the file doesn't have a jumbo icon, I can get the small icon.

Comment: I'm not sure .. but I think GetIconInfo will give information what icon you got. Also check what calls fail in Windows API often helps to figure what does not exist. Have you tried IShellItemImageFactory? SHCreateItemFromParsingName(path, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pImageFactory)); will give it. It works lot better than said IImageList from SHGetImageList in my experience.

Comment: I tried IShellItemImageFactory, now the problem is, if I have a file it has only 32*32 icon, if I use IShellItemImageFactory->GetImage image width and height are fixed to 256*256, it will return me a 256 size The size of the picture, and then there is a small icon of 32*32 in the middle of the picture, which is not very good, so I will see if I can find an API to determine the size of the largest icon of a file, and then I will go according to this size. Call IShellItemImageFactory->GetImage, this will work better.

Comment: @fanchenio 
You could use [SHGetFileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with the SHGFI_ICON flag to retrieve the handle to the icon that represents the file and the index of the icon within the system image list. And then you could call [GetIconInfo function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-geticoninfo) to retrieve information about the specified icon. By the way, why you couldn't set these types to be dpi-aware.